# are angular controllers within an ng-repeat section the same instance?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to have a section of html and an associated controller repeat, but what I am finding is that the controllers seem to be a single object. That is, when I change an attribute of one of the controllers it changes for all of them. Am I doing something wrong or is this the intended behavior?

[Here is a simplified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z66n6rzb/7/) which demonstrates the issue. I want each "upgrade slot" to have it's own `selectedUpgrade` value, but it seems that they are all connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slotCtrl` is set on the district div, not on the slot div. So each repeated slot uses the same controller. See https://jsfiddle.net/hzzq5j3h/

Instead of

```
<div ng-repeat="district in mainCtrl.districts" 
     ng-controller="slotController as slotCtrl">
    <h4>{{district.name}} slots:</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="slot in district.slots">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You want

```
<div ng-repeat="district in mainCtrl.districts">
    <h4>{{district.name}} slots:</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="slot in district.slots" ng-controller="slotController as slotCtrl">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doh! That's exactly right. I'm embarrassed I was hung up on this for so long. Thanks.